# MyEtherWallet 3.3.7 Withdraw ETH from DAO for ETH function not working

Tags: ether, myetherwallet, the-dao, dao, thedao-refund

so I am trying to recover my ETH from DAO using MyEtherWallet 3.3.7, as described in the Ethereum Wiki: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/The_DAO_Refunds#How_Do_I_Withdraw_The_DAO_Refunds_Using_MyEtherWallet.3F.

I downloaded version 3.3.7 of MyEtherWallet, and unlocked my account successfully. However, although it calculates the correct amount of ETC I should receive, it does not calculate the right amount of ETH in the Withdrawal contract and the ExtraBalance contract, as you can see on the screenshot:

[image]

It never loads the ExtraBalance tokens and the ETH on the right, and when I try to withdraw my ETH, it says "do you want to trade your XXX DAO for 0 ETH", instead of the correct amount of ETH.

Can someone help me with this problem? I am having a lot of difficulty in withdrawing my ETH from the DAO contract, and any help will be greatly appreciated :)